# How can I prevent Google maps from being dragged out of the upper and lower boundaries?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

#### When using the Google map api, the map will drag up and down and gray edges will appear.

[image]

The demo in google's documentation will also drag out the gray edge, but Google's [Official website map](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.468851,-118.3131224,8z) can be dragged to the top to stop dragging. Where is the effect?